# How to create PDF file in Python and put LaTeX data?

Tags: python, pdf, latex

I need to create pdf file with some LaTeX data.
What I have:

```
min_latex = (r"\documentclass{article}"
         r"\begin{document}"
         r"Hello, world!"
         r"\end{document}")

from latex import build_pdf

# this builds a pdf-file inside a temporary directory
pdf = build_pdf(min_latex)

# look at the first few bytes of the header
print bytes(pdf)[:10]

with open('temp.pdf', 'wb+') as f:
    f.write(pdf)
```

But I have the following error message:

```
File "temp.py", line 18, in <module> f.write(pdf) TypeError: argument 1 must be convertible to a buffer, not Data
```

Comment: Explain the errors, give us the log/ error message...

Comment: @Kartoch here's error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 18, in <module>
    f.write(pdf)
TypeError: argument 1 must be convertible to a buffer, not Data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pdf is not a string - you have to invoke one of its methods to save it:

```
pdf.save_to("/tmp/foo.pdf")
```

In general, it's a good idea to go into the interactive interpreter and paste in your program up to including the pdf = ... line. Then you can say `help(pdf)` to find out what you can do with that object.

Comment: Thank you for this little tip! It's absolutely awesome.